# Definition of an indefinite integral

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I am learning integration right now and I was wondering if there is something like the definition of a derivative but for an integral. So, to find a derivative we can do the following:

$$f'(x) = \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h}$$

Is there something like that for an integral?

Thanks!

Comment: But is that not a definite integral? What's the difference?

Comment: So does that mean that when I am asked to find the indefinite integral i.e. $\int \cos \theta$, the question is really asking me to find a definite integral from $\int_0^x \cos \, \theta$?

Comment: The formal definition of definite integral in your course will involve a limit of Riemann sums. The formal definition of indefinite integral will involve finding the functions whose derivative is $\dots$. **Very** different, but it turns out related through the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus.

Answer (score 1):

You can write it slightly differently, but this is often taken as the defintion of the definite integral:
$$
\int_{a}^{b} f(x) \; dx = \lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{i=1}^{n}f(x_i)\Delta x
$$
Here $\Delta x = \frac{b-a}{n}$ and $x_i = a + i\Delta x$.

To understand this definition better, you could take a look at this [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral#Riemann_integral).

There is a relation between the indefinite integral and the definite integral. The Fundamental Theorem of Calculus says that (assuming that $f$ is integrable)
$$
\int_a^b f(t)\; dt = F(b) - F(a)
$$
where $F$ is any antiderivative (i.e. $ F'(x) = f(x)$). Now given constant $a$ that would mean that
$$
F(x) = \int_a^x f(t)\; dt + F(a).
$$